# how append a element after an element

Tags: javascript, append

i want replace a button in a website
how select a element before a element?

better solution then

```
$('.col')[2]
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <button id="itemCaptureResultLeftButton" class="bt">&lt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
        
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button id="itemCaptureResultRightButton" class="btn">&gt;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

my code

```
var itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW = document.createElement("button");
itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW.setAttribute('id', 'itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW');
itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW.innerHTML = '&gt;';
itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW.className += "btn";
document.getElementById('itemCaptureResultRightButton').append(itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW);
//$('#itemCaptureResultRightButton').remove();
```

i expected

```
<button id="itemCaptureResultRightButton" class="btn">&gt;</button>
<button id="itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW" class="btn">&gt;</button>
```

i got

```
<button id="itemCaptureResultRightButton" class="btn">&gt;
<button id="itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW" class="btn">&gt;</button></button>
```

Comment: You need [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to append as a **sibling** of the previous button but you are appending it as a **child**, therefore you have this behaviour.

You can use [insertBefore](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp):

```
let refNode = document.getElementById('itemCaptureResultRightButton');
let parentNode = getElementsByClassName("col")[2];
parentNode.insertBefore(itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW,refNode);
```

You can also use [parentNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) to get access to the parent node and then append as a child:

```
let parentNode = document.getElementById('itemCaptureResultRightButton').parentNode;
parentNode.append(itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW);
```

And then you could remove the previous one as I understand you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `append()` the way you did it, which will add the new button as a child of the existing button, you should use `replaceWith()` to replace the existing button with the new button directly:

```
var itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW = document.createElement("button");
itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW.setAttribute('id', 'itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW');
itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW.innerHTML = '&gt;';
itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW.className += "btn";
document.getElementById('itemCaptureResultRightButton').replaceWith(itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW);
```

I noticed you want to replace the original button with a new button that only has a different `id`.
A simpler way to achieve the change you wanted is to use directly change the `id` attribute of the original button by using `setAttribute()` :

```
document.getElementById('itemCaptureResultRightButton').setAttribute('id', 'itemCaptureResultRightButtonSW');
```